# Rotate relative layout with buttons- touch event areas doesn't rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to rotate a `RelativeLayout` like this:

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I've try so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
            android:toDegrees="90"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="500"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    </rotate>
```

And this is my `.java` file:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
layout.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

This is really rotate my buttons layout but the buttons touch area aren't rotate.
I mean that the buttons view really looks like 90 degree rotated, but the touch area stay the same.

And advice?
Does my way (without `LayoutAnimationController`) is OK?

Comment: Because you have you have animate the buttonLayout. Get the idea of the full area you want to rotate

Comment: or show your xml where the above  design is created

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the answers above, In android there are two kinds of animations, view animation and property animation, the first - animates the view without changing the view itself which means after it will end you must set the views to the way you wanted them.
The latter - changes the view properties itself (width, height ,X ,Y and etc...) while animating.

In your case the latter is the right choose.

Furthermore, the property animation has better performance (it uses vsync) so if your app supports ics and above and you can use them, it will always be better choice.

Comment: Can u please add link with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are animating the representation of the view, so buttons and view are in reality at the exact same place.
To move the views, use the `ViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
layout.animate().rotation(90).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
int w = mainLayout.getWidth();
int h = mainLayout.getHeight();

mainLayout.setRotation(270.0f);
mainLayout.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
mainLayout.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mainLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = w;
lp.width = h;
mainLayout.requestLayout();
```

And layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffcc88"
    tools:context=".TestRotateActivity" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/rotate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rotate"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 10x! But your answer is NOT an animation, it's simple rotation. I need rotation with duration.